# Access subdomain behind NAT with port specified

Tags: subdomain, reverse-proxy, nat

- Let's say i have a reverse proxy behind NAT. My router blocks requests on ports 80 and 443 for security reasons (ISP provided modem/router).
- Let's also say i have registered on duckdns.org, giving me a subdomain of sub1.duckdns.org.
- Making a port forward, i am able to access sub1.duckdns.org:xxx, hitting the proxy.

How can i access my subdomains of that proxy?

GET'ing sub2.sub1.duckdns.org:xxx seems to translate org->duckdns->sub1->sub2

I need something like "sub2.(sub1.duckdns.org:xxx)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how that's possible if duckdns doesn't provide such a service. Essentially, duckdns are returning an `A` DNS record for `sub1.duckdns.org`, which has nothing to do with the `A` record of `sub2.sub1.duckdns.org`.

If you're using HTTP, perhaps something like `sub1.duckdns.org/sub2` would be good enough?